# Variable passed by = into isolate scope not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a directive I hope to make public for use and ridicule, and I've found a pretty major issue I can't figure out if its my controller code or my directive.

I have a variable I pass to the directive via '=' in the isolate scope. If I pass the variable as a child object of an object, it works perfectly in any case, but when I pass it a top level variable, it works in one case, any changes the directive makes are reflected in the parent scope, while in the second, any changes the directive makes are not seen in the parent

In the working case, I don't define the variable before it gets sent to the directive. It's modified in the directive, and shows up properly in the parent scope.

In the non-working case, it is defined before being sent to the directive, but none of the changes in the directive show in the parent scope.

In both case, I tried both predefining and removing any initial definitions of the variable being sent to the directive; in the working case, it continued to work, in the non-working case, no progress was made.

This is the first time I've seen a '=' scoped variable not change based on changes made in the directive, and I'm at a loss.

Unfortunately, I don't have a working case to show you. I put the code into a plnkr to show a co-worker, and you can see all my code to see if there's something stand out wrong, and while I'll try to put together a working case, it involves an API, a bunch of code around it, and I suspect my simplifying it to make a working plnkr will solve the problem and not help figure out the issue I'm having. Unfortunately, I don't even know what code I should show you directly, as SO only lets me link plnkrs if I have code here.

Basically I have a directive

```
<combobox data="dataList" value="result"></combobox>
```

Data can be sent in as an array of strings or an array of objects of this format: `{ 'value': 'car_3', 'display': 'BMW' }`. Value returns as an object of the same type (if an array of strings is passed to data, its converted to objects in that format).

In case 1, result comes back with the data the directive sets, in case 2, it never changes (it maintains it's initial value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hUCuZuBu9BUbdwD0V6AO

In the plnkr, main.js contains my directive, and both case files show how the directive is called in the HTML. I'm sure there's some junk code in there, as I've been debugging this like crazy...

Comment: if you are going to put a plunker up for review, you should at least ensure that the plunker works (no 404 errors) before posting the link.  There is **way** too much code in that plunker to start trying to debug your problem without first trying to solve the 404;  its likely that many will just ignore the plunker all together and attempt to answer based on what is in the question, which has the exact opposite problem, almost no code at all.

Comment: I did, however, make an attempt to review your code;  from what I saw, you have a scope property of `value` that you overwrite in your link function with `scope.value = { 'value': null, 'display': '' };`.  I'm not sure if this is where your directive breaks with no way to debug it, but maybe this might be a start.

Comment: I'm sorry Claies; I mentioned in the question that I wasn't sure how to pose this problem. I did say I'm having trouble distilling it into something simple, and that the plnkr isn't a working case, just a bunch of code. Also, I didn't get any 404 errors, so I didn't have an issue posting it. As for the scope overwrite, that is on purpose, and I fail to see why overwriting a value would cause it to not change in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

hmm without seeing your code it sounds an awful lot like you're dealing with the common (super frustrating!) problem of js primitives being duplicated inside of child scopes, causing an unexpected non-bi-directional chain of binding. Are you using dot syntax on your model to force prototype?

Check out:
"Not having a dot in your ng-model (or other places you need it!)"
http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/

Comment: I'd love to at the least show the plnkr with the code, but not sure what I should show in the question to allow me to link said plnkr. That said, the value I'm passing (or expecting) are objects; I thought objects weren't considered primitive types?

I actually know about this dot notation issue, and have had to convert a number of variables into single value objects, frustratingly. This code does work when I convert to wrapper objects.

Comment: if you put even a couple lines of code (or, technically, anything at all between two line breaks indented with 4 spaces) you can include your plunker link. Or you could add it as a comment to the main question

Comment: Added, because I thought of how I can be descriptive. I wasn't sure if just adding junk code would be against any SO rules; didn't wanna risk it, heh.